# Linking to specific twitter bootstrap tabs from URL on same page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a javascript noob and I'm wondering how do I implement the answer to this question?

[Twitter Bootstrap Tabs: Go to Specific Tab on Page Reload or Hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862233/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-go-to-specific-tab-on-page-reload)

I want to use this code on the same page that the tabs are located....

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Javascript to enable link to tab
    var url = document.location.toString();
    if (url.match('#')) {
      $('.nav-tabs a[href=#'+url.split('#')[1]+']').tab('show') ;
    } 

    // Change hash for page-reload
    $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown', function (e) {
      window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
    })
  </script>
```

Where inside the page containing the tabs should I plugg this in.

Again, so sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: If you want to simply show a tab form a link on the __same__ page, you don't need to use the approach do this, instead use the script see [this other answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360112/jump-to-specific-tab-from-another-tab-with-bootstraps-nav-tabs/15365279#15365279), with a working jsFiddle example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the code in the `$(document).ready()` function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 //your code here...
});
```

What you have above won't work as the DOM won't be ready when it runs. Using the `$(document).ready()` function will delay execution until the dom has loaded. It can go pretty much anywhere in the page containing the tabs. Some people think it should go within the `head` section, some think it should go at the end. But read here for more in-depth answers on that: [Where do I put the $(document).ready()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770234/where-do-i-put-the-document-ready)

See: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()

Answer (score 4):

[Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  // Javascript to enable link to tab
  var url = document.location.toString();
  if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href=#'+url.split('#')[1]+']').tab('show') ;
  }

  // Change hash for page-reload
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome! one question: when i paste in the url with "#" the page goes to where the #starts. How would I be able to just have the page go to the top? I can see how going to # would be useful for sections in wikipedia pages, but we are just using 3 horizontal tabs to just display different content

Comment: I'm stupid. I just realized that I misunderstood the question. I was looking for a solution that simply changes the url when you click on the tabs

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .nav-tabs a[href=#/mytab]