# JavaScript queries are not working at all but work when inserted in jquery 1.10.0 file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-1.10

I am new to jquery and JavaScript and have little understanding of how they work.  How come the script at the bottom does not run.  If I insert it at the bottom of the jquery-1.10.0.js it works, but not if I put it in the HTML file.  I understand that this is an old version of jquery but I have to use it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Sandbox</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sandbox.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.0.js">   
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $("td.odd").css("background-color","green");
            var squares=$("td");
            for (var i=0; i<squares.length; i++) {
                squares[i].innerHTML = "X";
            } 
            $("#heading").css("background-color","green").css("color","red");
            $("#instructions").fadeOut();
            $("#instructions").fadeIn();
            $("#instructions").slideUp();
            $("#instructions").slideDown();
            $("#instructions").animate({left:"150px", width:"250px", height:"150px"})
            $("td.odd").addClass("temp").removeClass("odd");    
            $("td.even").addClass("odd").removeClass("even");
            $("td.temp").addClass("even").removeClass("temp");
            $("#googlelink").attr("href","https://www.google.ca");
            //three new things
            //1
            $("#checkerboard").focusin(function(){
                $("body").css("background-color", "red");
            });
            //2
            $("#checkerboard").focusout(function(){
                $("body").css("background-color", "white");
            });
            //3
            $("#googlelink").removeAttr("href");
            $("#googlelink").attr("href","https://www.facebook.ca");
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="heading">The jQuery Sandbox</h1>
        <div id="instructions">
            <p><b>The jQuery 1.10.0 library is loaded up and ready to go. Open your browser's JavaScript console and start experimenting.</b></p>
            <p><b>Here are some ideas:</b></p>
            <ul>
                <li>Choose one of the colors on the checkerboard and change it with the <b>.css()</b> function (hint: it's made of "td" tags with classes named "even" and "odd")</li>
                <li>Fill in every checkerboard square with an X using the <b>.html()</b> function.</li>
                <li>Make this box (id="instructions") <b>.fadeIn()</b>, <b>.fadeOut()</b>, <b>.slideUp()</b> and <b>.slideDown()</b>.</li>
                <li>This box has the "position:absolute" property. Make it slide around with the <b>.animate()</b> function.</li>
                <li>Now make it slide around and change size at the same time. Create a command in this way that makes it "fold down"?</li>
                <li>Change the foreground and background color of the id="heading" element at the same time using chaining.</li>
                <li>Exchange the "odd" and "even" squares using <b>.addClass()</b> and <b>.removeClass()</b>. This can be done using 3 separate commands.</li>
                <li>Change <a id="googlelink" href="http://www.google.com" target="googlewindow">this link</a> (id="googlelink") so that it goes somewhere else using the <b>.attr()</b> function.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="checkerboard">
            <table>
                <tr id="row1">
                    <td class="odd"></td><td class="even"></td>
                    <td class="odd"></td><td class="even"></td>
                    <td class="odd"></td><td class="even"></td>
                    <td class="odd"></td><td class="even"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="row2">
                    <td class="even"></td><td class="odd"></td>
                    <td class="even"></td><td class="odd"></td>
                    <td class="even"></td><td class="odd"></td>
                    <td class="even"></td><td class="odd"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="row3">
                    <td class="odd"></td><td class="even"></td>
                    <td class="odd"></td><td class="even"></td>
                    <td class="odd"></td><td class="even"></td>
                    <td class="odd"></td><td class="even"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="row4">
                    <td class="even"></td><td class="odd"></td>
                    <td class="even"></td><td class="odd"></td>
                    <td class="even"></td><td class="odd"></td>
                    <td class="even"></td><td class="odd"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="row5">
                    <td class="odd"></td><td class="even"></td>
                    <td class="odd"></td><td class="even"></td>
                    <td class="odd"></td><td class="even"></td>
                    <td class="odd"></td><td class="even"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="row6">
                    <td class="even"></td><td class="odd"></td>
                    <td class="even"></td><td class="odd"></td>
                    <td class="even"></td><td class="odd"></td>
                    <td class="even"></td><td class="odd"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="row7">
                    <td class="odd"></td><td class="even"></td>
                    <td class="odd"></td><td class="even"></td>
                    <td class="odd"></td><td class="even"></td>
                    <td class="odd"></td><td class="even"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="row8">
                    <td class="even"></td><td class="odd"></td>
                    <td class="even"></td><td class="odd"></td>
                    <td class="even"></td><td class="odd"></td>
                    <td class="even"></td><td class="odd"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <form id="testForm" name="testForm">
                <input class="input" type="text" name="textField" value="Type Something Here">
            </form>

        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $("td.odd").css("background-color","green");
            var squares=$("td");
            for (var i=0; i<squares.length; i++) {
                squares[i].innerHTML = "X";
            } 
            $("#heading").css("background-color","green").css("color","red");
            $("#instructions").fadeOut();
            $("#instructions").fadeIn();
            $("#instructions").slideUp();
            $("#instructions").slideDown();
            $("#instructions").animate({left:"150px", width:"250px", height:"150px"})
            $("td.odd").addClass("temp").removeClass("odd");    
            $("td.even").addClass("odd").removeClass("even");
            $("td.temp").addClass("even").removeClass("temp");
            $("#googlelink").attr("href","https://www.google.ca");
            //three new things
            //1
            $("#checkerboard").focusin(function(){
                $("body").css("background-color", "red");
            });
            //2
            $("#checkerboard").focusout(function(){
                $("body").css("background-color", "white");
            });
            //3
            $("#googlelink").removeAttr("href");
            $("#googlelink").attr("href","https://www.facebook.ca");
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Notice I have it in two spots. Neither seem to work.

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770234/where-do-i-put-the-document-ready (please note: currently, your script is within a `<div>`)

Comment: If you are using document.ready you should just be able to put it with your other scripts (after jquery is loaded)

Comment: yes this works, the problem is my professor wants it on the html page.  That way he can quickly see the new code we added. Kinda dumb but what can i do?  Also @Katie.Sun i followed everything in that article and it didn't help

Comment: Once you moved it outside of the div it is fine. Can you look in your console and make sure you are loading your jquery file?

Comment: The console stays empty when i refresh the page rn

Comment: You don't need the script in the header. Just put it before the closing body tag. Try replacing your current jQuery link with this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"> ` to eliminate that as your problem

Comment: No need to pull the code outside a div .. your js code should run anywhere .. your problem is not with the version of jquery .. I think your problem is how to include the script and jquery .. including jquery and your js code not in one `<script>`  tag

Comment: i took out all my script and then just put some above the end body tag and it works. thanks a lot.

Comment: you need line to include jquery `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.0.js"></script>` after this line you can try `<script>YOUR JS Code HERE</script>` and test it for sure it will work if the path of jquery is right

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef he has it at the end of the html body, and I didn't suggest trying the different jQuery because of the version but because I thought he might not have been linking to his jQuery properly. The code in the head isn't even running as he posted it.

Comment: yes @Katie.Sun I got it .. but no need to move it from head to body .. anyway you solved his problem .. have a nice day :)

Comment: Basic rule is if a `<script>` tag has an `src` then it can not also have code inside the tag as text. The textual code will be ignored

Answer (score 0):

Moved code into Snippet Tool and it works properly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("td.odd").css("background-color", "green");
  var squares = $("td");
  for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    squares[i].innerHTML = "X";
  }
  $("#heading").css("background-color", "green").css("color", "red");
  $("#instructions").fadeOut();
  $("#instructions").fadeIn();
  $("#instructions").slideUp();
  $("#instructions").slideDown();
  $("#instructions").animate({
    left: "150px",
    width: "250px",
    height: "150px"
  })
  $("td.odd").addClass("temp").removeClass("odd");
  $("td.even").addClass("odd").removeClass("even");
  $("td.temp").addClass("even").removeClass("temp");
  $("#googlelink").attr("href", "https://www.google.ca");
  //three new things
  //1
  $("#checkerboard").focusin(function() {
    $("body").css("background-color", "red");
  });
  //2
  $("#checkerboard").focusout(function() {
    $("body").css("background-color", "white");
  });
  //3
  $("#googlelink").removeAttr("href");
  $("#googlelink").attr("href", "https://www.facebook.ca");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="heading">The jQuery Sandbox</h1>
<div id="instructions">
  <p><b>The jQuery 1.10.0 library is loaded up and ready to go. Open your browser's JavaScript console and start experimenting.</b></p>
  <p><b>Here are some ideas:</b></p>
  <ul>
    <li>Choose one of the colors on the checkerboard and change it with the <b>.css()</b> function (hint: it's made of "td" tags with classes named "even" and "odd")</li>
    <li>Fill in every checkerboard square with an X using the <b>.html()</b> function.</li>
    <li>Make this box (id="instructions") <b>.fadeIn()</b>, <b>.fadeOut()</b>, <b>.slideUp()</b> and <b>.slideDown()</b>.</li>
    <li>This box has the "position:absolute" property. Make it slide around with the <b>.animate()</b> function.</li>
    <li>Now make it slide around and change size at the same time. Create a command in this way that makes it "fold down"?</li>
    <li>Change the foreground and background color of the id="heading" element at the same time using chaining.</li>
    <li>Exchange the "odd" and "even" squares using <b>.addClass()</b> and <b>.removeClass()</b>. This can be done using 3 separate commands.</li>
    <li>Change <a id="googlelink" href="http://www.google.com" target="googlewindow">this link</a> (id="googlelink") so that it goes somewhere else using the <b>.attr()</b> function.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div id="checkerboard">
  <table>
    <tr id="row1">
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row3">
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row4">
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row5">
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row6">
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row7">
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row8">
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class="even"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <form id="testForm" name="testForm">
    <input class="input" type="text" name="textField" value="Type Something Here">
  </form>

</div>
```

If you're calling the script in your head, it should be something like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      // My Code Here
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  Some Stuff
  </body>
</html>
```

You can also do this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  Some Stuff
  <script>
  // My Code Here
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this second example, you do not need to call `.ready()` as the jQuery code will load after the other elements. That's all that `.ready()` does, is wait till the document has fully loaded before executing the jQuery.

Hope that helps.